# Repetative and android service, self calling once complete

Tags: java, android

I am not sure if I have this right or not, but I have some code that I need to run in the background of my android application, and once that is complete, I would like to wait 10 seconds, and then run the code again.

I currently have this working, but I am sure it ain't the right way to go about it and wondered if someone can give me a simple example, or tell me what I need to change to make this "the right way" to do it.

First I have my ScheduleService.java file.  This is where my code that I want to run it, and as you can see, once it is finished, it puts the thread to sleep for 10 seconds and then calls itself again, but this means that the code never actually completes (you should see the length of the stack trace if I get an error!)

ScheduleService.java

```
public class ScheduleService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "ScheduleService";

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startJob();
            }
        });

        t.start();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    private void startJob(){
        // all my code is here, and i do what i need

        // job completed. Rest for 10 seconds before doing another one
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //do job again
        startJob();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Now to start the service code, I have the following when my application starts (in my MainActivity.java file)

```
// stop just encase its already started
context.stopService(new Intent(context, ScheduleService.class));

// start service
context.startService(new Intent(context, ScheduleService.class));
```

In order to make sure that the service is started when the device restarts, I also have my StartOnBootReciever.java code

```
public class StartOnBootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "Autostart";

    /**
    * Listens for Android's BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast and then executes
    * the onReceive() method.
    */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        Log.d(TAG, "BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast received. Executing starter service.");

        // upload in background
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScheduleService.class);
        context.startService(intent);

        // This code will start the application once the device has been restarted
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Then in my AndroidManifest.xml file, I have the following

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="StartOnBootReciever" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.idamigo.ticketmachine.ScheduleService" />
```

This all works, but I feel that have code that is self-calling, and "never ending"

Comment: why you need to sleep for 10 seconds? please explain what your service is really doing. se we can Help you about it.

Comment: the app stores data from lots of other devices, and then uploads this data to the server.  So i would like to wait for 10 seconds, then i can see if there is any data to upload, and upload it.

Comment: where app is storing data? in Sqlite ? or SharedPreferences?

Comment: In SQLite database.  Each other device is like an "offline" device, which uploads to the "master" device, which has an internet connection.  This "master" device is the device that then needs to upload data to the server periodically....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **Service**, you have used `Thread.Sleep` which is unnecessary. Because Service will run continuously in the background until you stop it or System stops it.

**Example:**

```
public class ScheduleService extends Service {

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

      Timer timer = new Timer();
      timer.schedule(task,1,10000);
      return Service.START_STICKY;
  }

  TimerTask task=  new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      //do your task here.
    }
  };

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      return null;
  }
}
```

Go for Service only if you need to run a task continuously in the background. Otherwise, use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). IntentService will be stopped when there is no work for it so you don't need to manage its state by yourself.

Comment: But how will the IntentService know when there is work?  Do i need to start the service like i do above?  Will this IntentService keep starting itself up to check for work? Will 2 IntentServices ever be created at the same time, as i do not want that to happen

Comment: You have to start the IntentService like Service. But you don't need to worry about stopping the service. It will destroy once code executed in `onHandleIntent()`

Comment: Tried this, but nothing in the "run" function is actually ever called.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled my app, still nothing

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. Handler won't work inside intent service. See my updated answer.

Comment: This runs once, and not again... i want it to run 10 seconds after the code has finshed, so it can keep checking if there is anything to do..... I have also tried by removing the stopSelf() call, but still only runs once

Comment: after your task finished call the handler code. see the updated answer.

Comment: It won't run for every 10 seconds. It just run only once after 10 seconds.

Comment: I need it to run 10 seconds after it has run.  But it needs to continuely run, so it should run, wait 10 seconds, then run again, wait 10 seconds, run, wait 10 seconds, run.......

Comment: Ok check my code now. do your task inside the TimerTask it will every 10 seconds.

Comment: YAY! that did it.  Thanks for all your help! appreciate it